# How am I using the multiprocessing (python) module wrong?

Tags: python

Can someone help me figure out why the following code won't run properly? I want to spawn new processes as the previous ones finish but running this code automatically runs everything, i.e. all the jobs report finished and stopped when they arent, and their windows are open as well. Any thoughts on why is_alive() returns false when it is actually true?

```
import subprocess
import sys
import multiprocessing
import time

start_on = 33 #'!'
end_on = 34
num_processors = 4;
jobs = []

def createInstance():
    global start_on, end_on, jobs
    cmd = "python scrape.py" + " " + str(start_on) + " " + str(end_on)
    print cmd
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=processCreator(cmd))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    start_on += 1
    end_on += 1
    print "length of jobs is: " + str(len(jobs))

def processCreator(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processors = input("How many instances to run simultaneously?: ")
    for i in range(num_processors):
        createInstance()

    while len(jobs) > 0:
        jobs = [job for job in jobs if job.is_alive()]
        for i in range(num_processors - len(jobs)):
            createInstance()
        time.sleep(1)

    print('*** All jobs finished ***')
```

Comment: I haven't read all your question but have you looked at the multiprocessing module?

Comment: This really seems like a question better suited for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. You might find the people there more willing to help tackle something as complex as this. Stack Overflow is really only meant for getting help with specific code problems.

Comment: Code Review is only appropriate if there's *code* (and the other conditions given in the Help Center there are met). This is too broad for SO as-asked, but it's not a fit for CR either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I only suggested Code Review because op said "I currently have a python program"

Comment: I asked in code review with code and they said to come back here lol.

Comment: "If you have broken code, the right site to get helped is Stack Overflow. Be sure to post a MCVE that reproduces your problem there" http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151243/python-parallel-module?noredirect=1#comment284874_151243

Answer (score 0):

Your code is spawning 2 processes on each `createInstance()` call, I think that's messing the `is_alive()` call.

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=processCreator(cmd))
```

This will spawn 1 process to run `processCreator(cmd)`. Then, `subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)` will spawn a child process to run the command. This subprocess will return immediately, so the parent process.

I think this version will work, removing the usage of `multiprocess`. I also have changed the `cmd` definition([see docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)):

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time

start_on = 33 #'!'
end_on = 34
num_processors = 4;
jobs = []

def createInstance():
    global start_on, end_on, jobs
    cmd = ["python","scrape.py", str(start_on), str(end_on)]
    print(str(cmd))
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    start_on += 1
    end_on += 1
    print "length of jobs is: " + str(len(jobs))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processors = input("How many instances to run simultaneously?: ")
    for i in range(num_processors):
        createInstance()

    while len(jobs) > 0:
        jobs = [job for job in jobs if job.poll() is None]
        for i in range(num_processors - len(jobs)):
            createInstance()
        time.sleep(1)

    print('*** All jobs finished ***')
```

Comment: Also, you can have problems finishing the jobs. All jobs must end within 1 second to exit the while section, if not, you'll have a nice infinite loop.